# Request had insufficient authentication scopes in jupyter notebook install in gcp

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I've create a schema in bigquery and one table, while access the sql result of this table in jupyter notebook which is configure in GCP VM, getting "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

sql = """  SELECT * FROM odsdata.food_data """
df = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
df.head()
```

how to configure authentication for bigquery SQL result in jupyter notebook which is configure in same GCP VM account?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is related to the Access scopes in the VM. By clicking on the instance name, you can go to the instance details page. From there, at the bottom you can see the Access Scopes of the VM, verify that it has either "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" or the BigQuery access enabled. If you need to [edit these values](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes), you must first stop the instance.

In addition, from the same page you can check that the Service Account used in your VM. If you didn't change it, it should be using the Compute Engine default service account, which should have Editor permissions, thus, BigQuery access. If this is not the case, you can go to the IAM page and [grant BigQuery permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#top_of_page) to the Service Account used.